# JavaFX: Set Icon/Graphic of MenuItem by CSS

Tags: css, javafx, fxml

I want to set the icon of a MenuItem by CSS. I searched a lot and tried a lot, without any success right now.

Here is a small FXML example:

```
<MenuBar>
  <menus>
    <Menu text="File">
      <items>
        <MenuItem text="Open" styleClass="iconOpen" />
        <MenuItem text="Save" />
        <MenuItem text="Exit" />
      </items>
    </Menu>
  </menus>
</MenuBar>
```

Within CSS I use:

```
.iconOpen {
  -fx-background-color: red;
  -fx-graphic: url("open.png");
}
```

As result, the MenuItem only got a red background color. But no icon.

I can integrate the icon as ImageView for MenuItem directly in FXML, but than I can't style it by CSS. But I want to separate the styling (css) from structure (fxml).

Maybe someone can give me a hint. I don't what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a look at the [CSS Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#labeled), you will note that `-fx-graphic` is used only on `Label` and `ToolTip` nodes.

So this will work:

```
.iconOpen  {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
.iconOpen > .label {
    -fx-graphic: url("lock24.png");
}
```

since you are setting the graphic for the label of the menu item.

Comment: This could be used for changing icon through "hover" of CSS on MenuItem ?

Comment: I don't see why not. Make sure you apply it to the menu-item: `.iconOpen:hover > .label {... // your pic }`

Comment: Almost there !!! The new icon appeared next to the menu item (but without removing the old icon) and also on the left side of the shortcut (Shift+I). Any idea ? Thank you and sorry for asking you here...

Comment: Indeed, this is an old answer, and not the place for new questions. Please post a new question, you can link to this one.